# Is it possible to download data that I'm getting in chunks from server?

Tags: javascript, frontend, http-streaming

The server is sending the data in chunks. I want to download it on the browser as soon as I start receiving the data(in chunks).

How should I approach this requirement?

Comment: Please elaborate. If you receive the chunks, are you not already downloading them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.